# Access variables from multiple files in WordPress plugin + js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, variables, plugins

Hi guys I have an issue in a WordPress plugin development...

Basically the plugin has

- the main_file.php
- a file2.php
- and a js file

Into the main file I define some data and I can retrieve them using get_option(xx);
The main_file.php also attach a js that call file2.php

I need to access to some data I set into main_file.php within file2.php but global doesn't work and also get_option give me a Internal error.

Do you have any clue?

Comment: So, `main_file.php` serves a page which includes a javascript file, which in turn makes an Ajax call to `file2.php`, which would like to use some data that was defined in `main_file.php`? Is that an accurate reading of what you have going there?

Comment: main_file.php attach a js file to wordpress view page (a post or a page) using wp_enqueue_script.
When I see the wordpress page, the js is called and it call file2.php.
I need to retrieve some value that I defined into main_file.php and I also stored into get_option or get_post_meta..

Comment: .. I have found that and I am continuing invastigating
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/ajax-php-and-get_options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure thi is the right way to do it, and if it it safe...

However after long time I have discovered that putting

```
include_once('../../../wp-config.php');
include_once('../../../wp-load.php');
include_once('../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
```

allow me to access to get_option(variable) sithin file2.php and so, accessing it using js via ajax.

Hope this coul be useful for someone else and please do not heditate to suggest further methods.
cheers